# How do I hide files in Team Explorer Pending Changes View?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, team-explorer

I am using Visual Studio 2107.

Looking at the “Pending Changes” panel in Team Explorer, there are two list for “Included Changes” and “Excluded Changes”.

I can use the Filters option to display only files that match a certain pattern. However, I want to be able to ***hide*** files that match a certain pattern.

The reason is that I have a number of files regenerated during the development process; these files all have the same name in different projects. They clutter up the list when I am reviewing what to check-in.

Note that I don’t want to exclude these files from being checked-in; they will be checked-in to source control eventually. I just want to be able to review the Changes list without these files displayed until I want to see them.

It seems straightforward but I can’t seem to figure out how to do it. And I can’t seem to find the right phrasing for Google.

Comment: @Leo So far, the consensus seems to be that it can’t be done. That is unfortunate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I hide files in Team Explorer Pending Changes View?

If you don’t want to exclude these files from being checked-in, I am afraid you could not hide files in Team Explorer Pending Changes View.

According to the document [Develop code and manage pending changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/develop-code-manage-pending-changes?view=azure-devops#use-the-pending-changes-page-to-manage-your-work):

> Almost **every change** that you make to the files on your dev machine is
> stored in your workspace as a pending change until you check it in.
>
> If items that you don't need to check in appear regularly in the
> Promote Candidate Changes dialog box, you can select one of them, open
> its context menu, and choose Ignore this local item to ignore the
> item. You can also choose Ignore by extension or Ignore by file name
> to create a file that will cause Visual Studio to systematically
> ignore this kind of file.

So, Pending changes will detect all your changed files unless you don't want to check them in.

So, to hide files in Team Explorer Pending Changes View, we need to use `.tfignore` file to ignored files to folders that are mapped in a local workspace, they do not appear in the Pending Changes page in Team Explorer. When you want to check them into source control, you can move them out from `.tfignore` file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well that is a real shame. I'll mark this as the answer since more complete.

Comment: Unfortunately, .tfignore doesn't work reliably, and to my knowledge has not been fixed. [https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/tfignore-file-is-being-ignored-by-vs2019-latest-ve/919487](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/tfignore-file-is-being-ignored-by-vs2019-latest-ve/919487)

Answer (score 1):

Hiding files from Pending Changes is not supported without fully ignoring them.